# Impossible to connect via remote desktop on an Ubuntu 18.04 vm with a new user

Tags: xfce, remote-desktop, xrdp

I normally use xrdp to connect via remote desktop with an Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver) virtual machine. I have no problem with my admin user but if i create a new user, i am not able to see any desktop.

I have no error messages but i only see a light blue screen.

I use xrdp Version 0.9.5 and xfce.

Comment: 18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver), xrdp Version 0.9.5

Comment: download the script from this link and run it http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=14888 It will work for all users.

Comment: Now when i log with a new user i can see an ubuntu desktop with a password request (i think it depend on the first start) but i have the error "the virtualbox kernel service is not running". If i enter the password, the vm crashes.